# Problem parsing json response in ajax function using Selectize.js

Tags: c#, json, ajax, selectize.js

I'm trying to build a combobox with an autocomplete functionality for my c# mvc web application. Doing some research i found out Selectize.js is a good option to accomplish this task. According to the documentation, i need to use ajax to query the database and show some results. This is my ajax function:

```
 $('#codigosAlumno').selectize({
        create: false,       
        load: function(query, callback) {
            if (!query.length) return callback();
            console.log(query)
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Administrador/ConsultarAlumnosJSON?codigoFiltro=' + query,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    maxresults: 10
                },

                error: function () {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function (res) {           
                    var rspns = eval(res);
                    console.log(rspns);
                    callback(rspns);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My ajax function call this controller method:

```cs
 [ABETAuthorizeAttribute(ConstantHelpers.ROL_ADMINISTRADOR)]
        public JsonResult ConsultarAlumnosJSON(String codigoFiltro)
        {
            var listaAlumnos = context.Alumno.Where(x => x.codigo.Contains(codigoFiltro)).Select(x=>x.codigo).ToList();
            return Json(listaAlumnos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This method return json in this format:
["199810501","199810501","199810501","199810502","199910288","200815199","201110199"]

According to the documentation, that's the way to do it but when i type in the combobox nothing is being shown, even when there is data that match what i'm writting. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do not `eval` the response.  That is both completely unnecessary and a potential security problem.  If you need to do anything at all, it might be `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Im not using eval anymore but the issue is still there